# Composer - class not found after autoloading

Tags: php, composer-php

my class structure is as followed:

```
myproject
    |
    -------src (namespace PicoCore;)
            |
            -----objects (namespace PicoCore\Objects;)
            -----tests (namespace PicoCore\Tests;)
```

I've created composer.json from autoloading:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "PicoCore": "src",
            "PicoCore\\Objects" : "src/objects",
            "PicoCore\\Tests" : "src/tests"
        }
    }
}
```

I've created a testing script after installing:

```
<?php

require_once "../../vendor/autoload.php";

use PicoCore\Objects\User;

$user = new User();
$user->name = "asaf";
echo $user->name;

?>
```

User Class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: avivpaz
 * Date: 12/25/14
 * Time: 12:07 PM
 */

namespace PicoCore\Objects;

class User extends APIUser implements ConvertibleObjects
{


    /**
     * @var string User's Name
     */
    public $name;



    /**
     * @var string User's Push Id
     */
    public $pushId;


    /**
     * @var UserDevice User's device type
     */
    public $userDevice;

    /**
     * @var double The location latitude
     */
    public $latitude;

    /**
     * @var double The location longitude
     */
    public $longitude;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->label = USER_LABEL;
    }

    /**
     * init with APIUser
     * @param $APIUser APIUser
     * @return User type
     */
    public static function withAPIUser($APIUser)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->label=USER_LABEL;
        $user->id = $APIUser->id;
        $user->facebookAccessToken = $APIUser->facebookAccessToken;
        $user->picoAccessToken = $APIUser->picoAccessToken;
        $user->accessTokenExpires = $APIUser->accessTokenExpires;
        return $user;

    }

    public function ConvertObjectToCypherSyntax()
    {
        return '{id:"' . $this->id . '",name:"' . $this->name . '",picoAccessToken:"' . $this->picoAccessToken . '",accessTokenExpires:"' . $this->accessTokenExpires->getTimestamp() . '",latitude:' . $this->latitude . ',longitude:' . $this->longitude . '}';

    }

    static public function  ConvertNodeToObject($results)
    {
        $user = new User();
        if (is_null($results))
            return $user;
        $user->id = $results->getProperty('id');
        $user->name = $results->getProperty('name');
        $user->picoAccessToken = $results->getProperty('picoAccessToken');
        $user->latitude = $results->getProperty('latitude');
        $user->longitude = $results->getProperty('longitude');
        //    $user->userDevice = UserDevice::ConvertNodeToObject($results['userDevice']);
        if (!$results->getProperty('accessTokenExpires') == "")
            $user->accessTokenExpires = getDateTimeFromTimeStamp($results->getProperty('accessTokenExpires'));
        return $user;
    }

    static public function ConvertArrayToObject($array) {
      $user = new User();

      if (array_key_exists("id", $array))
        $user->id = $array["id"];
      if (array_key_exists("name", $array))
        $user->name = $array["name"];
      if (array_key_exists("pico_access_token", $array))
        $user->picoAcceessToken = $array["pico_access_token"];
      if (array_key_exists("access_token_expires", $array))
        $user->accessTokenExpires = getDateTimeFromString($array["access_token_expires"]);
      if (array_key_exists("device_type", $array))
        $user->deviceType = $array["device_type"];
      if (array_key_exists("latitude", $array))
        $user->latitude = $array["latitude"];
      if (array_key_exists("longitude", $array))
        $user->longitude = $array["longitude"];
      if (array_key_exists("userDevice", $array))
        $user->userDevice = UserDevice::ConvertArrayToObject($array["userDevice"]);

      return $user;
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $user = array();

        if (!empty($this->id))
            $user["id"] = $this->id;
        if (!empty($this->name))
            $user["name"] = urldecode($this->name);
        if (!empty($this->picoAccessToken))
            $user["pico_access_token"] = $this->picoAccessToken;
        if (!empty($this->accessTokenExpires))
            $user["access_token_expires"] = getMysqlDateTime($this->accessTokenExpires);
        if (!empty($this->latitude))
            $user["latitude"] = $this->latitude;
        if (!empty($this->longitude))
            $user["longitude"] = $this->longitude;
        if (isset($this->userDevice)) {
            $userDevice = $this->userDevice->toArray();
            if (!empty($userDevice))
                $user["userDevice"] = $userDevice;
        }
        if (count($user) > 0)
            return $user;
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get a can't find class exception.. any ideas ?

Comment: Does it work that way? $user = new PicoCore\Objects\User(); ?

Comment: Can you post the content of `User` class ?

Comment: @bub nope it doesn't..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With PSR-0

In order to use PSR-0, you need to change your structure layout to:

```
src/
└── PicoCore
    ├── Objects
    │   └── User.php
    └── Tests
```

And in your composer.json you need to add `PicoCore` namespace:

```
"psr-0": {
    "PicoCore\\": "src"
}
```

#### Alternative with PSR-4

If you want to keep your current file system layout, you can use PSR-4 instead of PSR-0. In order to use PSR-4, you need to update composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "PicoCore\\": "src",
        "PicoCore\\Objects\\" : "src/objects",
        "PicoCore\\Tests\\" : "src/tests"
    }
}
```

After you made your changes, run `composer dumpautoload` to regenerate autoload files.

Comment: That works! I also had to change my require once line to: require_once __DIR__ . "/../../vendor/autoload.php";

Answer (score 0):

If it's a namespace without class, it's must finish with \\
So :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "PicoCore\\": "src",
        "PicoCore\\Objects\\" : "src/objects",
        "PicoCore\\Tests\\" : "src/tests"
    }
}
```

and check file autoload

> composer/autoload_namespaces.php

see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-0

Comment: add trailing slash after src "PicoCore\\": "src/"
what is the content of composer/autoload_namespaces.php ?

Comment: It was a metter of psr-4 instead of 0